# How do you get the value of listItemId for sharepoint items in java

Tags: java, sharepoint

I'm trying to use the ListsSoap web service from sharepoint in java to get the attachment of a docx file that is currently on sharepoint. And trying to download the docx file into my local disk. However, right now I get error trying to get the XML from sharepoint in the following code.

I get the error 
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.

```
SharepointReference sharepointReference = new SharepointReference();
ListsSoap listsSoap = sharepointReference.getListAuth("sharepointId","sharepointPassword");
GetAttachmentCollectionResponse.GetAttachmentCollectionResult x = listsSoap.getAttachmentCollection("listName", "28");
```

The "28" inside the parameter is referring to the value of the ows_ID column of the listitems. I'm not sure if this is actually the listItemId of the list item which is taken by the second parameter of getAttachmentCollection.

Does anybody know if the error is actually thrown because of some Authentication issue or is it because of invalid listItemId?

Answer (score 0):

The logic of how you are setting up and authenticating is masked in your `SharepointReference` class and its `getListAuth` method. Not knowing the logic, we can't determine the cause. The logic below is a typical approach to accessing SharePoint list content over web services. You may want to try this. *This is not compile ready as I've borrowed bits and pieces from my solution (which I can't share for IP reasons)*

```
public void GetAttachments {
    String endPoint = "http://YourSiteUrlIncludingTheSubweb"+"/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

    //set proper authentication
    java.net.CookieManager cm = new java.net.CookieManager();
    java.net.CookieHandler.setDefault(cm);
    Authenticator.setDefault(new SPAuthenticator());

    //Connect to list
    Lists service = new Lists(new URL(endPoint+"?wsdl"),
            new QName("http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/", "Lists"));
    ListsSoap soap = service.getListsSoap();
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) soap;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "domain\username");
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endPoint);

    //get attachments
    port.getAttachmentCollection(...)
    .
    .
    .
}
```

and This is our SPAuthenticator.java class

```
public class SPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("domain\username","password".toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: While the posted code might help the OP, you don't give an answer to the original question. So, why doesn't the approach of the OP work and what did you do to overcome that problem? Please provide a bit more explanation.

Comment: @honk I should've elaborated before my response. The `SharepointReference` object and `getListAuth` methods are not part of SharePoint web services. My take is the actual logic is masked in the constructor and/or `getListAuth` method. The above snippet should be the logic his method should utilize.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You can edit your answer at any time. Please improve it by adding your explanation directly into the answer. The more complete your answer is, the higher is the probability that your answer gets upvoted.